# Installing Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have recently installed Windows 8 Preview. I would like to install Visual studio 2012. The problem is VS 2012 is looking for .Net 4.5.x. When I install .Net 4.5.x, it tells me that it is already part of the operating system. Any workarounds ?

Comment: There have been several beta releases of Windows 8 and VS2012.  Mixing doesn't work, you have to get the exact versions that were released around the same time.  RTM is available soon.  Yesterday if you have an MSDN subscription.

Comment: Here is another post about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027597/installing-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-on-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The latest Visual Studio RTM versions won't install on Windows 8 Release Preview.
You can try one of RC versions:

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29917

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29915

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue download Visual Studio 2012 though Microsoft Dream Spark, rather than any other source i had the same issue on two separate machines.... this fixed both.

Link to Dream Spark: https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=44

I hope this helps everyone.

Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Please Format the system and install the RTM Builds Of WINDOWS 8 and VS 2012