# Installing Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

While trying to install the Visual Studio 2012 ultimate trial on Windows 8 Release Preview I got the following error message

> The .Net Framework installed on this machine does not meet the minimum
> required version: 4.5.50709.

So I tried installing the required .net framework version, but that gave me the following error

> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating
> system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5
> redistributable.

I am running the Windows 8 release preview on a 32-bit Intel Core2Duo system, with Visual Studio Express already installed.

Answer (score 13):

This solution worked for me for at least Express 2012 for Web on 32-bit Windows 8 Release Preview:

1. Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full node in the regedit
2. Right click on the node, choose Permissions, then click "Advanced" button and change owner of this node to Administrators and then click OK and give Full Control permission to Administrators
3. Change the value of "Version" parameter to "4.5.50709"

I found this instruction at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/e968a2e7-a996-4492-b0c6-da94a1403cb6 . It also contains 64-bit windows registry path.

Comment: Changing the owner is through the `Owner` section on the top of `Advanced` window, yes? I was confused about that for a bit.

Answer (score 12):

Other solutions:

Solution A)

- Download the .NET 4.5 installer and extract it (run it with /x, or open in WinRAR, etc.)
- Go to the extracted folder and open ParameterInfo.xml. 
  Remove the TAG blockers, completely: remove the branch < blockers >.
- Execute SEtup.exe and try to install it again.

(It worked for me in Windows 8 Ultimate Version).

Solution B)

- Run regedit.exe.
- Edit Framework version key.

  - WIN64-bit: Go to the following key:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
  - WIN32-bit:Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full

NOTE: You'll need to change the permissions before you can edit anything.  First, change the owner to Administrators, then assign the Administrators principal with Full Control.
- Finally, simply change the value for "Version" to "4.5.50709".
To change permission for editing registry, in Regedit, select you key, right-click-->Permissions-->Advanced-->Owner, select Administrators, Apply. Then grand Full Control to "Administrators"

Comment: solution A didn't work for me  . about solution B , the registry entry of "Full" doesn't even exist...

Answer (score 5):

That isn't supported and isn't going to work. Both VS and Windows were evolving, and only a few very specific combinations of OS and IDE worked together. Since both are now RTM this should no longer be an issue, and MS are certainly not going to go out of their way to make these throwaway test platforms ensure compatibility.

If you are an MSDN or technet subscriber you should be able to download a Win8 RTM image *for development purposes* (testing, validation, etc). Otherwise you'll have to purchase and install Windows 8 retail, or install VS2012 on your existing OS (Windows 7, presumably). Likewise, VS 2012 RTM is available from MSDN. Note that VS2012 only supports "Modern UI" development (or whatever it is called this week) on Windows 8 (regular .NET framework development is supported both on Windows 7 and Windows 8).

Comment: +1 for *(or whatever it is called this week)*. And for the good answer of course.

Comment: I didn't get the only "Metro" development part. How can that be? Does that mean I'll have to use VS2012 Express for Web/Desktop?

Comment: @Robin Maben: I was a little confused as well. He's not saying Modern UI is the only thing you can do with VS2012 on Windows 8. He's saying Windows 8 is the only platform where you can do Modern UI development. If you're only going to work on desktop apps and you have the Ultimate edition, then there is no concern; all commercial editions of VS2012 are still capable of building desktop apps on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get 90 day trial of Windows 8 Enterprise from here now

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx