# Multiple Versions of .NET 4.5 - Two computers treat .NET 4.5 differently?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am developing on two machines, one desktop, one laptop. The desktop is running windows 7, and the laptop is running windows 8. Both have .NET 4.5 installed, and I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Most of the development I do is on the desktop, but I recently went to work on the laptop, and got the following prompt when I open my solution. Additionally, regardless of what I choose, it crashes VS2012 when I try to build the solution.

[image]

It seems like it doesn't recognize two version of .NET 4.5? Is that even possible?

Comment: Check with your .net versions in the laptop. Then install the .net framework 4.5

Comment: both have .NET 4.5 installed, and I have verified.

Comment: then degrade the project in desktop in 4.0 version. then check with laptop. Then upgrade to 4.5 in the laptop.

Comment: The first thing I would try is repairing the .NET install on the laptop and maybe even VS2012.  Crashing when you try to build the solution would seem to hint that there's a bigger issue here :)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/03/07/8108332.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx may be of help also.  Out of curiosity, are both machines 32/64bit or are they different?

Comment: is the laptop has the cp, rc of windows 8? then it may be a minor version problem like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027597/installing-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-edition-on-windows-8-release-preview)

Comment: both machines are 64 bit and the windows 8 is not the rc